# Getting error while implement Oracle storage using laravel

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-8

I have tried to upload file to Oracle object storage (oci) using `https://medium.com/@hassan_omar/custom-laravel-filesystem-provider-for-oracle-object-storage-4b18ab2a140` this tutorial. Everything done which is described as this tutorial. In my laravel 8 project aws s3 already implemented. I created an Oracle cloud account and created credential for storage bucket.

env

```
FILESYSTEM=oci
OCI_ACCESS_KEY_ID=f1b11a17f30931b8f62bc******
OCI_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=iIn4CKnKmE5/cuyIxz+*****YdYcSIBw=
OCI_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-hyderabad-1
OCI_BUCKET=my-oracle-bucket
OCI_URL="https://a***8ejkp17v.compat.objectstorage.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloud.com"
```

config/filesystems

```
'oci' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('OCI_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('OCI_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('OCI_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('OCI_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('OCI_URL') .  '/'.  env('OCI_BUCKET'),
]
```

I got this error while uploading to oci

```
Error executing \"PutObject\" on \"https://my-oracle-bucket.ax****jkp17v.compat.objectstorage.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloud.com/my-oracle-bucket/20230325143057WrmOc.jpg\"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'my-oracle-bucket.a****jkp17v.compat.objectstorage.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloud.com' (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://my-oracle-bucket.a****ejkp17v.compat.objectstorage.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloud.com/my-oracle-bucket/20230325143057WrmOc.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because S3Client builds the request URL internally by appending the bucket name at the beginning of the URL which OCI doesn't support.

We can disable this by setting `bucket_endpoint`  and `use_path_style_endpoint` to true in the service provider

Here's the code example

```
$client = new S3Client([
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $config['key'],
        'secret' => $config['secret'],
    ],
    'region' => $config['region'],
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'bucket_endpoint' => true,
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
    'endpoint' => $config['url']
]);
```

Comment: Thank you man.Now image is uploaded to my oci bucket.How can i show the image in blade. MY_OCI_URL/imagename.?.I was checked in my oracle dashboard.Images link likje https://objectstorage.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloud.com/n/ax***jkp17v/b/my-oracle-bucket/o/my-oracle-bucket%2F202304041215410OIdS.png

Comment: Divyank Do you know why 'my-oracle-bucket%2F' is prefixed with  image name.?